# How to handle keyboard events in gnome shell extensions?

Tags: gnome, gnome-3, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

How can I add an event or other method to listen to keypresses on a gnome shell extension? e.g. show a dialog with each key press showing the pressed key?

I can not find any example. The [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial) mentions a `keyboard` module, but with that common name searching is hard.

```
Class explanation
...
- General utils
   - Keyboard: Manage and define the keyboard events, etc. for gnome shell.
```

(read above as a quote from the docs linked above. it is styled as code because the quote styling for some reason do not preserve line breaks in this site)

I found some extensions using the bellow code for results similar to what i'm asking, but i, again, failed to find docs for the specific classes and methods:

```
workViewInjections['_init'] = injectToFunction(WorkspacesView.WorkspacesView.prototype, '_init', function(width, height, x, y, workspaces) {
        this._pickWorkspace = false;
        this._pickWindow = false;
        this._keyPressEventId = global.stage.connect('key-press-event', Lang.bind(this, this._onKeyPress));                                                                                
        this._keyReleaseEventId = global.stage.connect('key-release-event', Lang.bind(this, this._onKeyRelease));
        connectedSignals.push({ obj: global.stage, id: this._keyPressEventId });
        connectedSignals.push({ obj: global.stage, id: this._keyReleaseEventId });
        });
```

Also, no class named `keyboard` anywhere there...

--

edit1: more searching... i think i may have to use the `Clutter` api. but again, not much examples or documentation for that. farthest i went was this

edit2: more searching. looking on the gnome shell source code, on the main ui tree, i think the answer is to use the barelly mentioned `global` object that is available to the extension code. e.g.

`global.connect('key-press-event', function(if, i, know, the, signature){} );`

Comment: relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/86840/documentation-for-gnome-shell-extension-development

Comment: found the keyboard module: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/keyboard.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across this snippet in gcampax's [gtk-js-app template](https://github.com/gcampax/gtk-js-app/blob/master/src/window.js#L74) some time ago, which may be related to what you're doing:

```
// Due to limitations of gobject-introspection wrt GdkEvent and GdkEventKey,
// this needs to be a signal handler
this.connect('key-press-event', Lang.bind(this, this._handleKeyPress));
```

and

```
_handleKeyPress: function(self, event) {
    return this.main_search_bar.handle_event(event);
},
```

I haven't had a need to use keyboard events yet, and this is Gtk in GJS, but the same limitation may be affecting gnome-shell extensions.

**UPDATE**

I've been doing some keybinding stuff lately, and if attaching a signal handler to the global object is working, you can do something like this:

```
global.display.connect("key-press-event", (widget, event, user_data) => {
    let [success, keyval] = event.get_keyval(); // integer
    let keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(keyval); // string keyname

    if (keyname === "Control_L") {
        // Dialog code or eg. this.keys_array.push("<Ctrl>");
    }
});
```

There's also some [Shell keybinding code here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/windowManager.js#L1099-L1113) and *some* [shell-global documentation here](https://developer.gnome.org/shell/3.24/shell-shell-global.html) that might give you more clues. Wish I could help more but I'm wrestling my own GJS atm ;)

**ADDENDUM**

There is a [good answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/471606/gnome-shell-extension-key-binding/1182899#1182899) with an example class with informative logging, as well as a speculative explanation. I've also found this functionality is exposed over DBus which might be more convenient in some cases:

Bus Name: `org.gnome.Shell` -> Path: `/org/gnome/Shell` -> Interface: `org.gnome.Shell`

Relevant Methods:

- `GrabAccelerator(String accelerator, UInt32 flags)` -> `(UInt32 action)`
- `UngrabAccelerator(UInt32 action)` -> `(Boolean success)`

Signal:

- `AcceleratorActivate(UInt32, Dict of {String, Variant})`

Comment: Interesting, the main method, `... .connect('key-press-event', ...` is not mentioned on the shell-global doc.

Comment: and on the example linked, they use `gobal.display.add_keybinding()`... the shell-global list that property as being a `Metacity display object`. But searching for that term, i only find it on the shell object for gnome source comments.

Comment: Best I could find is https://people.gnome.org/~tthurman/docs/metacity/struct__MetaDisplay.html `MetaDisplay`, but it doesn't have an `add_keybinding()` method.

Comment: After some pointed searching, I found [an answer on superuser.stackexchange.com](https://superuser.com/questions/471606/gnome-shell-extension-key-binding/1182899#1182899) that gave me everything I need. I think it will probably do it for you too.

Comment: `global.display.connect("key-press-event", ...)` will not work because ["There never was such a signal on MetaDisplay"](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-bind-modifier-mousebutton-in-gjs/3743/2)

Answer (score 0):

For me `global.stage.connect("key-press-event", _handleKeyPress)` did the trick

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I type something inside application windows